# Regex in java matching digits, few special chars and alphabets

Tags: java, regex

I have a phone number which can contain below values:

```
• Digits: 0-9
• Special character: "#", "*", "-", "_", " ", "(", ")", "+", "?"
• Alphabets: "x", "X"
```

These above can be more than once in phone number. 
If any other value/character besides listed in above list is present it should fail.I tried creating regex but it fails with message "Dangling meta character '*'".

Below is the regex tried:

```
 if(!str.matches("([0-9]*|*|#|(|)|?|+|_|-)"))
   {
       System.out.println("--not matched--");
   }
```

Please help me in creating a regex for above.

Comment: @Aran-Fey-This does not answer by question

Comment: It doesn't? Why not?

Comment: It's about escaping special chars but I need to match digits, few special chars and only two alphabets. Please once go through my question and help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the regex `([0-9]*|\*|#|\(|\)|\?|\+|_|-)` do what you want? If no, why not?

Comment: It's not compiling shows invalid escape sequence

Comment: It looks like you are looking for `[0-9*#()?+_\\- ]*`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the characters `*`,`+`, `?` as they have regex meaning.

You also need to escape the `\` because you use java, so try

`str.matches("([0-9]*|\\*|#|\\(|\\)|\\?|\\+|_|-)")`

Comment: While this compiles, I'm pretty sure it will not match what OP want. Notice that `matches` expect from regex to match entire string.

Comment: @Pshemo-[0-9*#()?+_\\- ]* answer given by you matches my requirement. Thank you!!